# General hints on convergences of series of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Study the pointwise and uniform convergence of the following series of functions:
a)$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}\cos(3^nx)$$
b)$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^s}, s\in[1+h,\infty), h>0$$
c)$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{n^\alpha(1+xn^2)}$$
Could you please give me some general hints on how to find the convergence of infinite seris of functions? I know Weirstrass theorem and the definition of uniform and pointwise convergence. But I've just learned it today so I am pretty confused. Thank you!

Comment: If you just learned them today and are asking us for help on your confusion, you should start by showing us where your confusion starts when doing these problems.

Comment: I don't know what should I pursue, to begin with. My only tools are Weierstrass theorem and the limit of $f_n$ being 0?

Comment: For less specific questions, the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) is a good place.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

(1) $\;|\cos(3^nx)|\le 1\;,\;\;\forall\,x\;$

(2) $\;\forall\,s\in[1+h,\,\infty)\;,\;\;\cfrac1{n^s}\le\cfrac1{n^{1+h}}\;$

Comment: See that $\frac x{1+xn^2}<\frac1{n^2}$

Comment: @SimpleArt Yep, but there must be an absolute value there, and also $\;n^\alpha\;$ in the denominator influences. For example, for $\;\alpha\le-2\;$ the general term sequence doesn't even converge to zero.

Comment: Hm, so it is pointwise with respect to $\alpha$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

for the third.

if $x=0$, it converges.

if $x\neq 0$ it converges if $\alpha>-1$

since

$$\frac{x}{n^\alpha(1+xn^2)}\sim \frac{1}{n^{2+\alpha}}\; ( n\to +\infty)$$

Comment: See that $\frac x{1+xn^2}<\frac1{n^2}$

Comment: @SimpleArt What you see is not true. and $\alpha?$.